# I’m struggling with this question of gauss law application

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

I am confused with this question.What Gaussian surface do I take to calculate the electric field at the $q$ charge? Should it be a cylinder containing the whole system? Or should it be a cylindrical surface inside the bigger cylinder? If yes then why is the bigger cylinder not included? Please help

[image]

Comment: what happened to $a$ and $b$???

Comment: @HicHaecHoc I know I’m supposed to calculate the force on the charge which will be the net centripetal and from there on I’ll calculate ‘v’.But sir I have to find the electric field in order to calculate the force and without a correct Gaussian surface I won’t be able to find the field on Q ,that’s the question I asked,not the solution of the problem.

Comment: @JEB the field does not depend on the size of the cylinders no more than the field outside a sphere depends on the size of the sphere (assuming appropriate symmetry of course).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I know, but a good multiple chose exam would include a few $(a/b)$'s, or even a dimension'ed combination, to throw ppl off, and help the promising physics students get ahead ;-)

Comment: @JEB Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is that, if you want the field at a point $\vec r_p$, you will choose a Gaussian surface that goes through this point because then
\begin{align}
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S =\vert \vec E(\vec r_p)\vert \times S
\end{align}
for an infinitely long cylinder: the cylinder must be infinitely long so that there is no edge effect, the system cylindrical symmetry, and the field does not depend on the position inside the cylinder.

The assumption that the lengths of the cylinders are much greater than their radii means you can ignore fringing and assume the cylinder if as long as you wish.

In particular, if the point $\vec r_p$ is inside the larger cylinder, the Gaussian cylinder through $\vec r_p$ will not enclose this larger cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure the inner cylinder is equivalent to a line charge, and the outer cylinder doesn't matter.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elecyl.html

http://www.ncert.nic.in/html/learning_basket/electricity/electricity/electrostatics/electric_field_of_line_charge.htm

We then combine this with the equation for centripetal forces, and you should get your answer pretty quickly.